# Azure mobile app service keep getting it's pyodbc library version change without any actions

Tags: django, azure, react-native, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

We have a Django/React mobile app that is hosted in Azure with the an app service plan (python 3.8.17) on Linux. 2-3 times a week, it stops working because the version of the pyodbc changes without any action on our side. We need to log into the SSH and switch the library libmsodbcsql-17-10.so.4.1 to libmsodbcsql-17-10.so.2.1 and then everything comes back to normal. What can cause this issue ?

We checked if it was planned maintenance or any other Azure service that took action of some sort but couldn't find anything.